# React Native app works on Android with import errors

Tags: android, react-native

My React Native app works with import errors.  I have done everything needed to fix the errors, although Android Studio still says there are errors, even though my app builds and runs successfully.

Does anyone know how to remove these false errors?

[image: errors]

Comment: Android Studio ->  file -> invalidate cashes/restart

Comment: Done that many times, does not fix the errors

Answer (score 1):

Import errors created by gradle default usually, please check your gradle.build.
Make sure you have

On some cases, you manually import the files, so check the files if you manual import the files to your project.

Maybe you need to see this tutorial to setup your gradle:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-from-source

Thanks.

Comment: I was just about to send that link. Dependencies are explained in the link, the problem is in the build.gradle file probably.

Comment: I dont think this is the issue as I have two more RN apps I have made with the exact same RN version and app.gradle and build.gradle files (modified for each apps bundle). The other apps dont show any errors, although this one does, but they all build successfully and run successfully :/

Comment: Have you tried clean Project then rebuild the project?